# sending client to client messages without server interaction

Tags: php, web-services, webserver

I am not sure if I can explain this correctly…. But is there a way to send a message from one client to another without bringing the server into interaction…. I mean the server will setup the channel between two clients and the clients will communicate using that channel only…. No server interaction what so ever… much of what like `pubnub` does… so basically what I am trying to do is build something like `pubnub`… I know it is possible… if I’m not mistaken that is….. So, what are the things I need to get started… oh and I'm not sure what tag to put this question in... basically i want something like the following picture...

[image]

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: hey... i was just being polite...

Comment: Nice thought - wrong site. This isn't a discussion forum. Please read the link I included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with PHP, JavaScript or WebSockets. If you will open a connection between two clients, clients' system must allow a port to open at least. Which can not be done any of these. It requires an access to OS. If you could do this from browser, it would be a security issue.

You may can do this with a Java applet if it had to be done through browser. Which accesses to underlying JVM which can access to OS functions with proper permissions.

Comment: i have another question.. what does pubnub do... ??

Comment: PubNub makes is possible to do realtime client to client communication without requiring you to scale it with your own server(s). If you wanted to do what PubNub does, you would need a massively scalable network of servers that handle all the message publishes and send them onto all the subscribers (1 or millions of them - globally). Contact [PubNub support](https://www.pubnub.com/support/) if you have further questions.